# Debian Security Update Locations

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I need to download the Debian files that `apt-get update` retrieves. From my logs, it looks like the following are retrieved:

- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
- http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
- http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
- http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
- http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
- http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages

While there are URLs, they are clearly not full paths. How do I download the actual files associated with each of the above?

Comment: Debian 9 has onlñy a few months of support left. What you should be concerned with is the update to the current Debian 11.

Answer (score 0):

This question is handled in the post
[How do I generate a package download list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168352/how-do-i-generate-a-package-download-list)

The
[answer by Anwar](https://askubuntu.com/a/168353/963426)
contains this command :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated -y --print-uris | grep -o '\'http.*\' | tr "\'" " " > download-list
```

You will find more methods in the linked answer and also
in the other answers in this post.

Comment: A precaution from `man apt-get`: `--allow-unauthenticated` `Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about it. This can be useful while working with local repositories, but is a huge security risk if data authenticity isn't ensured in another way by the user itself. The usage of the Trusted option for sources.list(5) entries should usually be preferred over this global override. Configuration Item: APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated.` — The linked *answer by Anwar* is dated 2012. At that time there have been some issues with the authentication. But meanwhile this has changed.